# Why Contact object metadata is not returned when refresh server using Force.com Ide?

Tags: package, force.com-ide

I am using Force.com Ide and refresh the object from server.Here my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountCleanInfo</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>AssistantProgress</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContactCleanInfo</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>DandBCompany</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordItem</members>
        <members>DuplicateRecordSet</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>FeedItem</members>
        <members>Idea</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>LeadCleanInfo</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityCompetitor</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>OpportunityTeamMember</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>Pricebook2</members>
        <members>PricebookEntry</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>SocialPersona</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>StreamingChannel</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <members>UserProvisioningRequest</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
      <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

I noticed other objects contains detail but Contact metadata only contains this value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>
```

I tried refresh again but still it return the same.I check Contact in the server, the object still available with all fields etc but why in Eclipse metadata it only return above.

Also, I check Add/Remove metadata, contact object is included.
[image]

Comment: can you check your permissions on contact object?

Comment: Are you getting any particular errors on the Problems tab?

Comment: I've had this error before, you should look at `Add/Remove Metadata`, click refresh schema button, then verify that in the dialog that under Standard Object `Contact`, that all fields are checked.

Comment: @cropredy , I checked the Add/Remove Metadata.Contact is available as screenshot above.

Comment: @Viasur I check the Problems tab, no error.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 , I can view Contact field in Setup -> Contact. I can retrieve other object metadata, only Contact it gave me two lines metadata xml file.

Comment: Try one more thing. Create new project and select option to download everything and check if it works.

Comment: Unidha. Just to be clear, when you click add/remove - standard objects - contacts.  There is a checkbox and expand icon.  When you click expand you should see all fields checked.

Comment: It may be a bug with version 36. Can you try with a lower version?

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 , ya it works. cropredy , I check the field not visible , same goes to other object.But other object return metadata, Contact no. RajeshShah I lower down not working.I just create new project and start all over again.